# Access Google Ads Information in Android/iOS App

Tags: android, react-native, branch.io, google-ad-manager

I have an app that is hosted on Play Store. In order to promote it, I am running ads on Google Adwords. On the Google dashboard, I can see views/clicks and all this data. But is there a way to access Google Ads information like campaign_name, etc in my Android app code.

Usecase: I want to access Google Ads information so that I can tag information to new Registrations. Registration source: Google Ads, Campaign: Google_Campaign_Id.

PS: I am using branch integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Google Ad Campaign information inside your application, using Branch's [SAN deferred deep linking feature](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/san-deferred-deep-linking).

The Branch SDK will return the `SAN ad data` for installs/reinstalls and a typical response looks like this -

```
{
"session_id": "775732418224171111",
"identity_id": "775732414789038000",
"link": "https://abc.app.link?%24identity_id=775732414789038000",
"data": {
    "+is_first_session": true,
    "$3p": "a_facebook",
    "~advertising_partner_name": "Facebook",
    "+click_timestamp": 1557204842,
    "~secondary_publisher": "facebook",
    "~campaign": "ABC",
    "~campaign_id": "33333377778880001",
    "~ad_set_name": "DEF",
    "~ad_set_id": "4444333399990002",
    "~ad_name": "XYZ",
    "~ad_id": "22223333377770003",
    "~feature": "paid advertising",
    "~ad_objective_name": "APP_INSTALLS",
    "~channel": "Facebook"
},
"device_fingerprint_id": "777778888855555222"
}
```